# Multiple User Tweetpony Stream

Tags: python, twitter

I am facing a bit of a problem basically I'm using tweetpony with python to capture stream data from twitter. This works fine with one user with the following code:

```
import Tweetpony

class StreamProcessor(tweetpony.StreamProcessor):
        def on_status(self, status):
                print "%s: %s" % (status.user.screen_name, status.text)
                return True

pony = tweetpony.API(comsumer_key=***, consumer_secret=***, access_token=***, access_token_secret=***)

processor = StreamProcessor(pony)

pony.user_stream(processor = processor)
```

However this only works for one user. How can I adapt this code to enable multiple user support?

Thanks in advance

Cameron

Answer (score 0):

You must pass load_user='user'

```
pony = tweetpony.API(comsumer_key=***, consumer_secret=***, access_token=***, access_token_secret=***, load_user='user')
```